# How to optimize and speed up this matrices multiplication in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

According to the gradient equation, matrices multiplication is given by
[image]

where both `@` and `*` are needed. Here is the code if readers are interested:

```
# parameters
beta     =  0.98 
alpha    =  0.03
delta    =  0.1
T        =  1000
loop     =  1
dif      =  1
tol      =  1e-8

kss      =  ((1 / beta - (1 - delta)) / alpha)**(1 / (alpha - 1))
k        =  np.linspace(0.5 * kss, 1.8 * kss, T)

k_reshaped   =  k.reshape(-1, 1)
c            =  k_reshaped ** alpha + (1 - delta) * k_reshaped - k
c[c<0]       =  1e-11
c            =  np.log(c)
beta_square  =  beta**2

# multiplication
I   =  np.identity(T)
E   =  np.ones(T)[:,None]
Q2  =  I

while np.any(dif > tol) and loop < 200:
    J   =  beta * Q2
    B   =  inv(I - J)

    Q3  =  np.zeros([T,T])
    ini =  np.argmax(c + (B @ (J * c) @ E).flatten(),axis=1)
    Q3[np.arange(T),ini]  =  1


    gB  =  2 * B @ (J * c @ E) @ (beta * Q2 * c @ E + B @ (np.linalg.matrix_power(I - J, 2) * c @ E)).T / beta_square
    B   += 0.1 * gB

    dif  =  np.max(np.absolute(Q3 - Q2))
    kcQ  =  k[ini]

    Q2   =  Q3
    loop += 1
```

Basically, it is folloing the stochastic gradient descent algorithm, matrix `B` is initialized by `B = inv(I - J)` and evolving by `B += 0.1 * gB`, `J` varying along with `Q2`, and `Q2` needs to be determined in each iteration. However `Q2` is a sparse matrix each column only has one one and the rest being zero, in the code it is like:

```
ini =  np.argmax(c + (B @ (J * c) @ E).flatten(),axis=1)
Q3[np.arange(T),ini]  =  1
...
Q2  =  Q3
```

The code currently demonstrates a 1000 by 1000 matrices operation, could this be optimized and run even fatster?

Comment: I might turn it into a complete answer if I find time to analyse it more, but here is a low-hanging fruit: Your `B` is just `np.identity(T) / (1. - beta)`. Don't waste a full-fledged matrix multiplication applying the `B @  …` steps in the final expression for what's just a multiplication with a scalar.

Comment: Thanks, @Homer512. My apologies for not mentioning that the code in the question is actually a simplified one, the multiplication runs multiple times in a iteration loop, and the matrix `J` is changing along with each iteration, `J = beta * I` is just the initialized value. I am so sorry that not mention this key information, the question has already been edited according to your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you still call `B = inv(I - J)` in each iteration or is this also just an initialization thing?

Comment: Yes, ‘B’ and ‘J’ keep updating during iterations.

Comment: Inverting huge matrices is not a good idea in general. Typically you replace it with something like `linalg.solve`. If you keep updating, you may be able to avoid repeated decompositions. For example scipy allows [updating QR decompositions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr_update.html#scipy.linalg.qr_update). See if that is possible for you. Please show more of your update routine

Comment: Thank you again @Homer512! I has re-edited the code and descriptions to explain the update routine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some improvements:

- `beta * Q2` is computed twice, `J` can be used instead the second time.
- `J * c` is also computed multiple time while it can be done once. The same for `I - J`.
- `B @ (J * c) @ E` and `B @ (J * c @ E)` are mathematically equivalent, but the later is faster in your case and can also be computed once.
- CPython optimizes (almost) nothing and Numpy performs operations eagerly so doing `0.1 * (2 * Matrix / beta_square)` actually compute a new matrix `M2 = 2 * Matrix`, then a new one `M3 = M2 / beta_square`, then another one `M4 = 0.1 * M4`. Creating many temporary matrices like this is expensive because it is a memory-bound operation and the memory bandwidth is pretty limited on modern machines (compared to the computing power), not to mention filling new temporary arrays is generally slower than already filled ones (because of virtual memory and more specifically page faults). Thus, it is faster to do `(0.1 * 2 / beta_square) * Matrix` (since multiplying float is much faster than multiplying big matrices).
- Some basic operations like `np.argmax(c + tmp3.flatten(), axis=1)` or `np.max(np.absolute(Q3 - Q2))` can be easily accelerated using Numba. In fact, most
- In-place operations are generally faster than out-of-place ones (again, because of expensive temporary arrays). You can use them thanks to the `out` parameter of basic functions (e.g. `np.multiply(A, B, out=C)`). That being said, the benefit is quite small here since `inv` takes a significant time.
- Assuming `B` is not needed in the end of the loop, you can use `np.linalg.solve` instead as mentioned by Homer512. Solving a system is significantly faster for large matrices (`O(n**3)` versus `O(n**2)`) and often more accurate. See [Don’t invert that matrix](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/). For example, `inv(I-J) @ b` can be replaced by `solve(I-J, b)`. The benefit of using `solve` is not so big though in your specific use-case because of the sparse `I-J` matrix.
- If `B` is actually used, in the end of the loop, then this is a bit more complex. Numba can help to write a relatively fast matrix inversion specifically for sparse matrices like in your use-case (since the one of Scipy turns out to be pretty slow).
- `np.linalg.matrix_power(tmp0, 2) * c` can also be optimized in Numba for sparse matrices.

Here is a (barely tested) implementation using Numba:

```py
@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[::1])', parallel=True)
def compute_ini(a, b):
    n, m = a.shape
    assert b.size == m and m > 0
    res = np.empty(n, np.int64)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        max_val, max_pos = a[i, 0] + b[0], 0
        for j in range(1, m):
            val = a[i, j] + b[j]
            if val > max_val:
                max_val = val
                max_pos = j
        res[i] = max_pos
    return res

@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def max_abs_diff(a, b):
    return np.max(np.absolute(a - b))

# Utility function for invert_sparse_matrix
@nb.njit
def invert_sparse_matrix_subkernel(b, out, i1, n, eps):
    for i2 in range(n):
        if i2 != i1:
            scale = b[i2, i1]
            if abs(scale) >= eps:
                for j in range(n):
                    b[i2, j] -= scale * b[i1, j]
                    out[i2, j] -= scale * out[i1, j]

@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def invert_sparse_matrix(a, out):
    eps = 1e-14
    n, m = a.shape
    assert n == m and out.shape == (n,n)

    b = np.empty((n, n))

    for i in nb.prange(n):
        out[i, :i] = 0.0
        out[i, i] = 1.0
        out[i, i+1:] = 0.0
        b[i, :] = a[i, :]

    for i1 in range(n):
        scale = 1.0 / b[i1, i1]
        if abs(scale) < eps:
            b[i1, :].fill(0.0)
            out[i1, :].fill(0.0)
            invert_sparse_matrix_subkernel(b, out, i1, n, eps)
        elif abs(scale-1.0) < eps:
            invert_sparse_matrix_subkernel(b, out, i1, n, eps)
        else:
            b[i1, :] *= scale
            out[i1, :] *= scale
            invert_sparse_matrix_subkernel(b, out, i1, n, eps)

@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def sparse_square_premult(a, premult, out):
    eps = 1e-14
    n, m = a.shape
    assert n == m
    assert premult.shape == (n, n)
    assert out.shape == (n, n)

    for i in nb.prange(n):
        out[i, :] = 0.0
        for j in range(n):
            if abs(a[i, j]) >= eps:
                for k in range(n):
                    out[i, k] += a[i, j] * a[j, k]
        out[i, :] *= premult[i, :]

def compute_numba():
    # parameters
    beta     =  0.98 
    alpha    =  0.03
    delta    =  0.1
    T        =  1000
    loop     =  1
    dif      =  1
    tol      =  1e-8

    kss      =  ((1 / beta - (1 - delta)) / alpha)**(1 / (alpha - 1))
    k        =  np.linspace(0.5 * kss, 1.8 * kss, T)

    k_reshaped   =  k.reshape(-1, 1)
    c            =  k_reshaped ** alpha + (1 - delta) * k_reshaped - k
    c[c<0]       =  1e-11
    c            =  np.log(c)
    beta_square  =  beta**2

    # multiplication
    I   =  np.identity(T)
    E   =  np.ones(T)[:,None]
    Q2  =  I

    J = np.empty((T, T))
    tmp0 = np.empty((T, T))
    tmp1 = np.empty((T, T))
    tmp2 = np.empty((T, 1))
    tmp3 = np.empty((T, 1))
    tmp4 = np.empty((T, T))
    B = np.empty((T, T))

    while np.any(dif > tol) and loop < 200:
        np.multiply(beta, Q2, out=J)
        np.subtract(I, J, out=tmp0)
        invert_sparse_matrix(tmp0, B)

        Q3 = np.zeros((T,T))
        np.multiply(J, c, out=tmp1)
        np.matmul(tmp1, E, out=tmp2)
        np.matmul(B, tmp2, out=tmp3)
        ini = compute_ini(c, tmp3.flatten())
        Q3[np.arange(T), ini] = 1

        factor = 0.1 * 2 / beta_square
        sparse_square_premult(tmp0, c, tmp4)
        np.add(B, (factor * tmp3) @ (tmp2 + B @ (tmp4 @ E)).T, out=B)

        dif = max_abs_diff(Q3, Q2)
        kcQ = k[ini]

        Q2 = Q3
        loop += 1

compute_numba()
```

Note that the `invert_sparse_matrix` function still takes a significant time (>50% on my machine) though it is about 3x faster than `inv` and about as fast as `solve`. It is an improvement of the [naive inversion algorithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_Inverse_Algorithm) with few optimizations for very sparse matrices. It can certainly be optimized further (eg. using tiling) but this is certainly not trivial to do (especially for novice programmers).

Note the compilation time takes few seconds.

Overall, this implementation is about 4~5 times faster than the initial one on my i5-9600KF processor (6 cores).

Comment: Thank you Jerome, I really appreciate your efforts! And thanks for taking me to see the power of Numba for the first time, I have learnt so much with these functions! Although it has a little "typos" if you don't mind I mentioning here,  `c` in function `compute_ini` should be replaced with `a`; `c` in function `sparse_square_premult` should be replaced with `premult`, and there will be all. I am so grateful for your detailed answer!

Comment: Glade you appreciate :) . Thank you for the proposals. I have fixed the code.